# Invert Array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is:Enter an array of strings from the standard input, using the function `invert` to invert each string. The inverted string must not contain digits.
Prototype function is: `invert(char **array,int n);`

Here' s my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void processing_string(char *s);
void invert(char **array,int n)
{

   if(n>0)
   {
       processing_string(array[n-1]);
       invert(array,n-1);
   }


}

void processing_string(char *s)
{
   int d=strlen(s);
   for(int i=0;i<d/2;i++)
   {
       char c=s[i];
       s[i]=s[d-i-1];
       s[d-i-1]=c;
   }
   char *t=(char*)calloc(d+1,sizeof(char));
   for(int i=0,j=0;i<d;i++)
   {
       if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')
       {
           t[j++]=s[i];
       }
   }
   strcpy(s,t);
   free(t);
}
int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("n=");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   char *array[n][20];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       scanf("%s",array[i][20]);
   }

   invert(array,n);
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      printf("%s",array[i][20]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my program breaks, after entering the strings, I don't think I'm entering the strings as I should, and I'm not forwarding them well to the invert function?

Thanks in advance !

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

`array[i][20]` is out-of-range of the 20-element array `array[i]`, so you mustn't read nor write the "element".

Instead of the out-of-range access, you should:

1. Declare an array of `char*`
2. Allocate a buffer and assign to the array.
3. Read strings to the buffer.

Applying this, your `main` function will be like this:

```c
int main(void)
{
   int n;
   printf("n=");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   char *array[n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       array[i] = malloc(20);
       /* TODO: detect and handle allocation error */
       scanf("%19s",array[i]);
   }

   invert(array,n);
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      printf("%s",array[i]);
   }

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      free(array[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Also note that:

- You should specify the maximum length of strings to read like `%19s` instead of `%s` to prevent buffer overrun.
- Casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).